# Shared memory segment Permission denied

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I am using shared memory segment to shared data and changes when I run other files.

My code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>      
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <signal.h>    
#include <stdbool.h>   
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h>   
#include <sys/shm.h>   
#include <sys/wait.h>  

bool eaten = false;
void onInterruptSignal()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nPellet PID is: %d - Died due to the interrupt !-Eaten : %s\n ", getpid(), eaten ? " True " : "False");
    exit(0);
}
void onTerminationSignal()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nFish PID: %d - Died due to the termination !-Eaten : %s\n ", getpid(), eaten ? " True " : "False");
    exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, onInterruptSignal);
    signal(SIGTERM, onTerminationSignal);

    int sharedMemoryID; // Shared memory ID which will be assigned in it when the shared memory segment create successfully
    key_t keyValue = 1337;
    char(*sharedDataArray)[10][10]; 

    // Create shared memory segment which return some value. But it returns -1 if it is not able create shared memory segment
    if ((sharedMemoryID = shmget(keyValue, sizeof(char[10][10]), IPC_CREAT )) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while creating memory segment.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Add the sharedDataArray in Shared memory so that it can be access by others
    if ((sharedDataArray = (char(*)[10][10])shmat(sharedMemoryID, NULL,0)) == (char(*)[10][10]) - 1)
    {
        perror("Error while attching sharedDataArray to shared memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    int row = rand() % 10;
    int col = rand() % 10;
    while (*sharedDataArray[row][col] != '#')
    {
        row = rand() % 10;
        col = rand() % 10;
    }
    *sharedDataArray[row][col] = 0x50; // My terminal doesn't support extended ASCII, so we won't be using 0x50.
    while (row < 9)
    {
        *sharedDataArray[row][col] = '#';
        row++;
        if (*sharedDataArray[row][col] == 'F')
        {
            *sharedDataArray[row][col] |= 0x50;
            eaten =
                true;
            sleep(1);
            break;
        }
        *sharedDataArray[row][col] = 0x50;
        sleep(1);
    }
    if (!eaten)
    {
        *sharedDataArray[row][col] = '#';
    }
    else if (*sharedDataArray[row][col] == 0x50)
    {
        *sharedDataArray[row][col] = 'F';
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("Pellet PID is: %d, X: %d, Y: %d - eaten: %s\n", getpid(), row, col, eaten ? "True" : "False");
    exit(0);
}
```

I am getting error on while attached the shared memory it says

```
Error while attching sharedDataArray to shared memory.
: Permission denied
```

I had try all commands to clear shared memory segment which is `ipcrm` and then restart also shutdown my PC. But when i open again it gives me the same error as I mentioned above.

Anyone know how I get rid off this error please ?

EDITED

`shmget()` create a shared memory id, by running `ipcs -m` it shows the shmid which is created but it does not have persmissions.
How I grant them permit?

[IPCS -m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwoGW.png)

TIA

Comment: `*sharedDataArray[row][col]` is wrong, it's the same as `*(sharedDataArray[row][col])`. You want `(*sharedDataArray)[row][col]` instead. Or, as a slightly different solution, make `sharedDataArray`  pointer to an array (i.e. `char (*sharedDataArray)[10]`). Then you don't need to add an extra dereference, and can just use plain `sharedDataArray[row][col]`.

Comment: I think that's not the issue, yesterday the same code has been run. Today it gives me this error. But for your information i changed what you said still getting the same error `permission denied`

Comment: Oh it wasn't meant as an answer to your problem, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer. :) But it's something that would have lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

If your program creates the shared memory object, it is created with permissions set to to 0, i.e. no permissions at all. See e.g. the documentation of `shmflg` in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html

You might need something like

```
#include <sys/stat.h> // for S_IR*** & S_IW*** macros

shmget(keyValue, sizeof(char[10][10]), IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

Your code might have run without error before if there was already a shared memory object with sufficient permissions.